# How to plot a complex table relation on excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

How can I generate a table as displayed in the image attached using Microsoft excel. The x and y axis in yellow are simply perfect squares while The table content is composed of axis sums. I cannot generalize a cell formula to correctly sum the y and x axis for any cell.

The problem a am facing is this.Lets say I want to compute the value of cell B3, I can manually enter into the cell: `=(B1+A3)`. However I cannot duplicate this formula onto other cells to give the desired outcome.

I need a generalized formula for any cell. I am thinking along the lines:  `=(letterofgivencell [1] + numberofgivencell [A]`.

I need the table to investigate patterns in Pythagorean triples and the automation would be helpful.

[image: attached image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Any links to excel tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel assumes all cell references are relative unless you tell it otherwise. So to get your formula to work you will need to make some references absolute using the `$`.

For instance, to get the formula to always look at the column A, you will need to place the `$` in front of the column address but leave the row address alone. For example; `$A2`. To get the formula to always look at the first row, you would use `B$1`.

Using these references tells Excel to Always look in column A, but use relative rows, and to always look at the first row, but use relative columns. What this results in is a formula in `B2` of the following...

```
=$A2+B$1
```

Then when you drag this down to other cells, it will calculate correctly for you.

[image]